# How to check if struct contains another struct in Go?

Tags: go

I have a struct called `Car` and `Motorbike` that are compositions with other structs. For example:

```golang
type HasSeats struct {
  ...
}

type HasDoors struct {
   ...
}

type Car {
   HasSeats
   HasDoors
}

type Motorbike {
   HasSeats
}
```

I now have an instance of `Car` and `Motorbike`. What is the easiest way to find out if the instances belong to a type that have `HasSeats` and `HasDoors`? I found a way through the `reflect` module but that is utterly noisy code. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
func CheckIfObjectHasDoors(carOrBike interface{}) bool {
    // ... ??
}
```

Comment: *"I found a way through the reflect module but that is utterly noisy code."* -- `reflect` is your only option.

Comment: i love go for everything except this. Thanks

Comment: The problem with the approach here is that you are trying to treat embedding like class-based inheritance, which Go purposely does not have. Switching to using more specific interfaces like below is one way to do this, but there's also a good chance that the actual non-contrived problem should not be approached via embedding which you should also consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an interface unique to each embedded type:

```
type Seats interface{ Seats() *HasSeats }
type Doors interface{ Doors() *HasDoors }
```

Implement the interface on each of the types:

```
func (x *HasSeats) Seats() *HasSeats { return x }
func (x *HasDoors) Doors() *HasDoors { return x }
```

Use [type assertions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to determine if a composed type contains one of the embedded types:

```
var mb interface{} = &Motorbike{}
if _, ok := mb.(Seats); ok {
    fmt.Println("mb has seats")
}
if _, ok := mb.(Doors); !ok {
    fmt.Println("mb does not have doors")
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/UeXgQoYu5tr

The interface methods are declared the receiver because it seems likely that the application will want direct access to the value.  Example:

```
type HasSeats struct {
    Color string
}

...

var mb interface{} = &Motorbike{HasSeats: HasSeats{Color: "red"}}
if s, ok := mb.(Seats); ok {
    fmt.Println("mb has seats and the seat color is", s.Seats().Color)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/DsCpoW4HsUI

Remove the return values if that's not something that you want.

Comment: Holy smokey, that's exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated!